# Can not Open database 'books' requested by login in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to create a database programmatically and create a table in it.
This is my code :

```
 string connectionstr = string.Format(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog={0};Integrated Security=True", "books");
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(connectionstr);

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Data");
        dir.Create();

        string str3 = @"CREATE DATABASE [books] ON  PRIMARY 
        ( NAME = N'books', FILENAME = N'D:\DATA\books.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )   
         LOG ON 
        ( NAME = N'books_log', FILENAME = N'D:\DATA\books_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.filegroups WHERE is_default=1 AND name = N'PRIMARY')     
        ALTER DATABASE [books] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str3, myConn); 
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConn.Close();
```

but i am getting the error:

> Cannot open database "books" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Master-PC\Master'.

what can i do to solve this?

Comment: As the error says, you are not allowed access to the database. You either need to add login data to the connection string or allow anonymous connections.

Comment: "Cannot open database "books" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'Master-PC\Master'." - grant access....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, reading your query it is clear that the books database doesn't exist at the connection time. You try to create it with your query.
Change your connection string and connect to 'master' database

```
string connectionstr = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=master;"
                       @"Integrated Security=True";
```

then execute your query, (this will create the database 'books'), close the connection and reopen it with the original "InitialCatalog=books" string